# Select rows where 'A1' is followed by 'A2'

Tags: query

I have a set of entries like:

```
Id ColA   

1 A1   
2 A2   
3 B   
4 A2   
5 A1   
6 C   
7 A1   
8 A1   
9 A2   
10 D
```

In pairs 1, 2 and 8, 9 the first line has A1 in colA and the following line has A2 in colA. How can I select these two pairs?

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't mention any specific DBMS I'll assume first that there are no window functions:

```
select A.Id, A.ColA, B.Id, B.ColA
from T as A
join T as B
    on A.Id + 1 = B.Id
where A.ColA = 'A1'
  and B.ColA = 'A2'
```

Assuming that window functions do exists:

```
select Id, ColA, Lead_id, LeadColA
from (
    select Id, ColA
         , Lead(id) over ( order by Id ) as Lead_Id
         , Lead(ColA) over ( order by Id ) as Lead_ColA
    from T
)
where Id + 1 = Lead_id
  and ColA = 'A1'
  and Lead_ColA = 'A2'
```

All untested, but you should get the idea

An alternative to @Vérace suggestion for a more tabular format is to use a lateral cross join that transpose the result. I.e.:

```
select X.Id, X.ColA
from T as A
join T as B
    on A.Id + 1 = B.Id 
cross join lateral ( values (A.Id, A.ColA)
                          , (B.Id, B.ColA) 
                   ) X (id, ColA)
where A.ColA = 'A1'
  and B.ColA = 'A2'
```

For SQL server I believe `cross apply` can be used in the same way. DB2, Oracle, Postgres all implement `LATERAL`, MySQL does not. The same technique can be applied with window functions as well:

```
select x.Id, x.ColA
from (
    select Id, ColA
         , Lead(id) over ( order by Id ) as Lead_Id
         , Lead(ColA) over ( order by Id ) as Lead_ColA
    from T
) as Y cross join lateral ( 
               values (y.id, y.cola)
                    , (y.lead_id, y.lead_cola) 
) as X (id, cola)
where y.Id + 1 = y.Lead_id
  and y.ColA = 'A1'
  and y.Lead_ColA = 'A2'
```

Answer (score 2):

Lennart's first query produces a result like this (i.e. side-by-side):

```
id|cola|id|cola
1|A1|2|A2
8|A1|9|A2
```

If you want a result like the one below (i.e. in a more "tabular" format), which
might be better for you?

```
id|cola
1|A1
2|A2
8|A1
9|A2
```

then use this query:

```
SELECT
t1.id, t1.cola
FROM tab1 t1
JOIN tab1 t2 ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
WHERE t1.cola = 'A1' AND t2.cola = 'A2'
UNION
SELECT
t1.id, t1.cola
FROM tab1 t1
JOIN tab1 t2 ON t1.id - 1 = t2.id
WHERE t1.cola = 'A2' AND t2.cola = 'A1'
```

A bit more ungainly, but it might be the result you want?

The equivalent LEAD() windows function query would be (though this is very ungainly! - perhaps some genius out there can suggest a better solution?

```
select xx.id,xx.cola
from (
    select id, cola, Lead(id) over ( order by id ) as lead_id, Lead(cola) over ( order by Id ) as lead_cola
    from tab1
) AS xx
where Id + 1 = Lead_id
  and cola = 'A1'
  and lead_cola = 'A2'
UNION
select yy.id, yy.cola
from (
    select id, cola, lag(id) over ( order by id ) as lead_id, lag(cola) over ( order by Id ) as lead_cola
    from tab1
    -- ORDER BY id DESC
) AS yy
where Id - 1 = Lead_id
  and cola = 'A2'
  and lead_cola = 'A1'
```